# csv into mysql by php

Tags: php, mysql, excel

Hello i'm trying to import data from a .csv file into mysql table. Below is the script i'm working with. After running it, only print_r($_FILES) was executed, and it didnt insert into the data base.

```
 <?php session_start(); ?>
 <?php require('includes/dbconnect.php'); ?>
 <?php require 'includes/header.inc.php'; ?>

 <?php
  if(isset($_POST['SUBMIT']))
  {
     $fname = $_FILES['csv_file']['name']; //Acquire the name of the file
     $chk_ext = explode(".",$fname);

     $filename = $_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name'];
     $handle = fopen($filename, "r");       //Open the file for readability
     while (($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
     {
        $sql = "INSERT into biodata (student_number, fname, lname, level) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]')";
        mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
     }
     fclose($handle);
     echo "Successfully Imported";
 }
 else
 {
     echo "Invalid File";
 }

print_r($_FILES) ;
?>
```

Comment: Which one of `Successfully imported/Invalid file` shows up?

Comment: Now it's showing Invalid File.

Comment: Aha. So `$_POST['SUBMIT']` is not set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query has problem.
Its expecting 4 columns (as you specified in column list) but you supllied only 3 columns.

```
$sql = "INSERT into biodata (student_number, fname, lname, level) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]')";
```

Comment: It was a combination of several things. The script is correct. My INSERT and VALUES parameters were not the same, then i did "submit" and "SUBMIT" which are different. But all those is solved now. Thanks for your time and patience...

Answer (score 0):

First of all check whether file was opened successfully:

```
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
if( !$handle){
  die( 'Cannot open file fore reading');
}
```

That's actually only place you're not handling correctly (hope you have error reporting turned on, because this could only be problem with `fgetcsv()` and error report would be crucial).

Comment: It was a combination of several things. The script is correct. My INSERT and VALUES parameters were not the same, then i did "submit" and "SUBMIT" which are different. But all those is solved now. Thanks for your time and patience...

Answer (score 0):

Once you've worked out how to access the uploaded file, you could also look into using LOAD DATA INFILE. If you use the LOCAL keyword (LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE), that should work even on shared hosting. For some examples, see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html

This has the benefit of being much, much faster than large numbers of INSERTs, which is especially relevant for large CSV files. Plus, it's quite easy to use.